# Using ORDER BY on a multiple LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, left-join

I have this long query that I finally got to work but I am unable to `ORDER BY date_time_added`, which is a field that is in all the tables except for `user_accounts` and `relationships` table.  How do i make it work correctly?

```
$sql = "select distinct pb.user_id, pb.Full_name,
tv.why_onsite3, tv.onsite3_id, tv.other_date as onsite3_date, 
tv.user_allowed as tv_user_allowed, np.onsite4_name ,  
np.onsite4_id, np.other_date as onsite4_date, np.user_allowed 
as np_user_allowed, pml.med_name , pml.med_id, pml.other_date 
as pml_date, pml.user_allowed as pml_user_allowed, pl.onsite5_name,
pl.onsite5_test_id, pl.other_date as some_stats_date, pl.user_allowed as   
pl_user_allowed, chlp.problem_name_is , chlp.current_problem_id, 
chlp.other_date as chlp_date, chlp.user_allowed as chlp_user_allowed,
pphl.onsite10_health_prob_id , pphl.onsite10_problem_name_is, 
pphl.other_date as pphl_date, pphl.user_allowed as pphl_user_allowed,
al.onsite_id , al.onsite_name, al.other_date as onsite_date, 
al.user_allowed as al_user_allowed, sl.onsite2_id , sl.onsite2_name, 
sl.other_date as onsite2_date, sl.user_allowed as sl_user_allowed,
hal.onsite6_id , hal.reason_for_admit, hal.other_date as hal_date, 
hal.user_allowed as hal_user_allowed, il.onsite9_id , il.onsite9_name, 
il.other_date as il_date , il.user_allowed as il_user_allowed
from user_accounts pb left join some_stuff tv on pb.user_id = tv.user_id
left join some_onsite4s np on pb.user_id = np.user_id
left join some_med pml on pb.user_id = pml.user_id
left join list_hal hal on pb.user_id = hal.user_id
left join list_for_things il on pb.user_id = il.user_id
left join list_on  sl on pb.user_id = sl.user_id
left join some_all al on pb.user_id = al.user_id
left join some_list  pphl on pb.user_id = pphl.user_id
left join some_stats pl on pb.user_id = pl.user_id
left join some_probs chlp on pb.user_id = chlp.user_id

where (pb.user_id in (select fb.friend_id from relationships fb 
where fb.user_id = '$uid')
or pb.user_id in (select fb1.user_id from relationships fb1 
where fb1.friend_id = '$uid')
)

group by pb.user_id ORDER BY date_time_added DESC LIMIT $startrow, 20";
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: if it,s in multiple table you'll have to ORDER BY <table_name>.date_time_added

Comment: but i want to sort it uniformly... i want the query to use that column in all tables and sort by date_time_added DESC.

Comment: @ariel Is `user_id` the Primary Key in all those (11) tables that are joined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ORDER BY clause, you have to specify what is the exact column you are ordering by. That means you have to prefix the column that is used for ordering, because you have multiple columns that are called the same in multiple tables.

Other option is to restructure the query completely and use UNION operator with multiple SELECT statements. Each SELECT statement would pickup a group of data from one table and order that group by column from that table.

The solution depend on the data that you want to output - the context of the data.

Comment: Hey, any idea how i can do #1? I am a bit new so not sure what you exactly what you mean.

Comment: do you mean something like tv.date_time_added, np.date_time_added, etc...?

Comment: It depends on what you want to return from this query. If you want to return data in this format that you provided above, then you have to write something like this:
ORDEY BY np.date_time_added, tv.date_time_added....

This means that you are first ordering everything by np.date_time_added, then by tv.date_time_added etc...

Keep in mind that when you are ordering in SQL, NULL values go first if you order ASCending, or Last if you order DESCending.

Comment: Ok in that case it wont' work for me.  I wanted to sort it uniformly.  I am unsure as to how to rewrite the script..

Comment: There is no logic in sorting them uniformly, just think about it. You have 2 rows with two columns, each of the are dates. No think about what it means to sort these rows 'uniformly' when you have 2 columns to choose to order by. I think you need UNION operator. Please check my answer above.